# log4J setSyslogHost(...) equilivant in log4j2

Tags: java, log4j2

I am migrating a large codebase from log4j to log4j2.   Log4j has a method to set the SyslogHost.

```
syslog.setSyslogHost(syslogDomainName);
```

I am looking for an equivalent in log4j2.

For completeness, the original log4J code looked like this:

```
SyslogAppender syslog = (SyslogAppender)Logger.getLogger("available-loggers").getAppender("syslog");
syslog.setSyslogHost(syslogDomainName);
```

The new code is looking to be a bit more complicated:

```
org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger logger
        = org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger("available-loggers");
    org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger coreLogger
        = (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger)logger;
    org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext context
        = (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext)coreLogger.getContext();
    org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configuration configuration = (Configuration)context.getConfiguration();

    Appender appender = configuration.getAppender("syslog");

    SyslogAppender syslog = (SyslogAppender) appender;
...
```

plus the replacement for

```
syslog.setSyslogHost(syslogDomainName);
```

Edit to add - I am wondering if I can use the AppenderBuilder to create a syslog appender with the correct hostname.

```
syslog.newSyslogAppenderBuilder().withHost(syslogDomainName);
```

EDITED - 
I am still having trouble making this work.

The log4J2.xml socket configuration below works for basic logging and is what I'm using:

```
<Socket name="syslog" port="514" host="${sys:log4j.syslog.host}" protocol="UDP" ReconnectionDelay="200">
            <JsonLayout2/>
    </Socket>
```

We have a log collector in AWS that can go away at any time, then scale back up with a new IP address.  I need to figure out how to get it to switch to that to that new IP.

Log4J1 was pretty simple to do with the syslog.setSyslogHost during runtime.  Any ideas on what I am missing in Log4J2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first question I would ask is "Why do you want to do this"? If it is because you need to determine the host name dynamically I would point you at Log4j's Lookup mechanism. If you are wanting to log events in RFC 3164 (BSD) format, the SyslogAppender is normally configured as

```
<Syslog name="bsd" host="targetHost" port="514" protocol="TCP"/>
```

If you want to set targetHost dynamically then do something like:

```
<Syslog name="bsd" host="${sys:syslogHost}" port="514" protocol="TCP"/>
```

which would get the hostname from a system property named "syslogHost". See [Lookups](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html) for more lookup options or you can write your own [custom Lookup](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/extending.html#Lookups).

But if, for some reason, you really need to programatically configure the Appender then there are multiple ways to do it which are described on the [Log4j web site](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html). Which you choose depends on whether you are programmatically creating the configuration or whether you want to modify and existing configuration.

To programmatically create a configuration Log4j recommends using a ConfigurationBuilder. This follows Log4j's normal mechanism of creating a configuration in two passes. In the first pass whatever the configuration dialect is (including the ConfigurationBuilder) is converted into a node tree. In the second pass the node tree is converted into the actual configuration. The second pass is generally common to all configurations built this way. So when you look at the ConfigurationBuilder API you won't be building specific classes. Instead you will be creating configuration components, which will later cause the corresponding classes to be created.

Modifying an Appender of an existing configuration cannot be done in a thread-safe manner so it is not allowed. Instead, you can create a new Appender with the same name and start it, remove the existing appender from the Configuration, add the new Appender, modify all the LoggerConfig objects to reference the new Appender instead of the old one, then stop the old Appender. You can find an example of this on Log4j's [custom configuration](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html) page.

I should also note that Log4j's SocketAppender, on which the SyslogAppender is built, accepts a DNS name that returns multiple ip addresses. If the connection fails the SocketAppender will try to reconnect at any one of the ip addresses.

Comment: I am having trouble making this work. 

The log4J2.xml socket configuration below works for basic logging and is what I'm using:



<Socket name="syslog" port="514" host="${sys:log4j.syslog.host}" protocol="UDP" ReconnectionDelay="200">
   <JsonLayout2/>
    </Socket>


We have a log collector in AWS that can go away at any time, then scale back up with a new IP address.  I need to figure out how to get it to switch to that to that new IP.

Log4J1 was pretty simple to do with the syslog.setSyslogHost during runtime.  Any ideas on what I am missing in Log4J2?

Comment: Use a DNS name for the host. If it has multiple ip addresses Log4j will fail over to the next one when a connection fails. It should also pick up new ip address settings as they change.

Comment: Thanks rgoers.  It did not pick up new ipAddresses as they changed unfortunately.  It never tried to reevaluate it.  The only way I was able to get this to work is to remove the old appender and add a newly created appender.  This is not ideal, but it would be much better if it would resolve the DNS on it's own if the IP changes.

Comment: Whenever the TCPSocketManager needs to reconnect it does   InetAddress[] addresses = InetAddress.getAllByName(host);  Is there some other way it needs to be done?

Comment: That should work.  I only expect a single host, so when I do it manually I use InetAddress.getByName("remoteaddress").getHostAddress()

Perhaps I didn't let my test run long enough?  I will try it again to verify.